# Is there a way to add a row selected listener on JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

I am using addMouseListener (that has many method to implement)
 and can add add keyListener also.
Is there a better way to get a row selected listener?
Thanks.

Comment: please clarify what you really want: be notified when the _selection_ of a row changed or when the _data_ of a row changed? The two answers are for one of those requirements :-) Apart from that, in Swing you never-ever want a keyListener and rarely a mouseListener.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to listen to row **selection** changes (i.e. not value changes inside the row), you can use this: `yourJTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(yourListener);` ?

Comment: +1, It did helped me :-), the same goes for the below answer too.

Answer (score 9):

have you tried?

```
    jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            if(e.getType() == e.UPDATE){
                System.out.println(e.getColumn());
                System.out.println(e.getFirstRow());
                System.out.println(e.getLastRow());
            }
        }
    });
```

@assylias  yeah there is a selected in the question not a changed. My mistake misread the question.

Comment: +1, It did helped me :-), the same goes for the above answer too.